How to reposition a window in LibGDX after it is resized with setWindowedMode() method
On an MS/Windows platform, when the user changes the window size of my app I capture it in the resize() method. I want to preserve the aspect ratio of the window, so if necessary,  I'll alter its size by calling the setWindowedMode() method. However, when I do that LibGDX then automatically repositions the window to the center of the screen. How can I prevent that repositioning from happening?  Or, can I reposition it back myself?
I create a LWJGL3 window to paint my app in using this:
    Lwjgl3ApplicationConfiguration config = new Lwjgl3ApplicationConfiguration();
    config.setWindowedMode( 1900, 980 );
    config.setWindowPosition( 10, 40 );
    config.setBackBufferConfig( 8, 8, 8, 8, 32, 0, 0 );
    config.setResizable( true );
    config.setWindowSizeLimits( 400, 400, 1900, 980 );


You can do this by calling setPosition (and getPosition) on Lwjgl3Window, which you can access on Gdx.graphics by calling getWindow.
As the implementation of the Gdx.graphics is platform dependent, you will need to cast it to the correct type for the platform (desktop, android or web) before  using it.
One way of doing that is to let each Launcher class of you project inject something into your game that can get and set the position of the window, for example for a DesktopLauncher it might look something like this;
First, in the core-project, add a WindowPlacer interface:
public interface WindowPlacer {
    Vector2 getPosition();
    void setPosition(Vector2 position);
}

Then, in your DesktopLauncher, instanciate a desktop-specific implementation of that:
public class DesktopLauncher {
    public static class DesktopWindowPlacer implements WindowPlacer {
        @Override
        public Vector2 getPosition() {
            Lwjgl3Window window = ((Lwjgl3Graphics) Gdx.graphics).getWindow();
            return new Vector2(window.getPositionX(), window.getPositionY());
        }

        @Override
        public void setPosition(Vector2 position) {
            Lwjgl3Window window = ((Lwjgl3Graphics) Gdx.graphics).getWindow();
            window.setPosition((int)position.x, (int)position.y);
        }
    }

    public static void main (String[] arg) {
        Lwjgl3ApplicationConfiguration config = new Lwjgl3ApplicationConfiguration();
        config.setWindowedMode(3120 / 2, 1440 / 2);
        config.setForegroundFPS(60);
        config.setTitle("libGDX Sandbox");
        // Inject an instance of DesktopWindowPlacer here to allow the platform-independent
        // core project access to window location
        new Lwjgl3Application(new MyGdxSandbox(new DesktopWindowPlacer()), config);
    }
}

Then in your ApplicationListener or ApplicationAdapter, you use that injected WindowPlacer to query and set the window position when resize is called:
public class MyGdxSandbox extends ApplicationAdapter {

    private WindowPlacer windowPlacer;
    private OrthographicCamera camera;
    private SpriteBatch batch;
    private Texture img;
    private float initialAspectRatio;

    public MyGdxSandbox(WindowPlacer windowPlacer) {
        this.windowPlacer = windowPlacer;
    }

    @Override
    public void create () {
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        img = new Texture("badlogic.jpg");
        initialAspectRatio = (float) Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / (float) Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
        float viewportWidth = 640.0f;
        float viewportHeight = 640.0f / initialAspectRatio;
        camera = new OrthographicCamera(viewportWidth, viewportHeight);
        camera.position.set(camera.viewportWidth / 2,camera.viewportHeight / 2,0);
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        float viewportWidth = width;
        float viewportHeight = width / initialAspectRatio;
        
        // Get the window position
        Vector2 currentWindowPosition = windowPlacer.getPosition();
        Gdx.graphics.setWindowedMode((int)viewportWidth, (int)viewportHeight);
        camera = new OrthographicCamera(viewportWidth, viewportHeight);
        camera.position.set(camera.viewportWidth / 2, camera.viewportHeight / 2, 0);
        
        // Set the window position
        windowPlacer.setPosition(currentWindowPosition);
    }
    

Again, you would need different implementations of WindowPlacer for each platform, and which class to cast to depends a little on what version of libGDX you are using, this example is based on version 1.12.0.

I'll dive into this. thanks.  Do you think the automatic centering feature can be disabled?

I am not sure if it can be disabled automatically, @Mike, but it was easy to use the method I described in the answer to avoid it snapping back to center.

Well, that was a forehead-slapper!  I should have been able to figure that out.... but didn't. :) That's how learning goes - a mentor teaches you principles so you can learn how to apply them yourself. Thank you for your insight.

This seems like a good enhancement request for LibGDX: resizing and repositioning windows always go hand-in-hand, and why they give you the ability to resize it and not reposition it is perhaps an oversight.  I guess they should also report whether a window is maximized and give you the ability to set or unset it too.
